# Kivy graph doesn't appear in widget

Tags: python, plot, graph, widget, kivy

I'm trying to find a solution to embed a graph within a kivy widget. There seems to be only one example of using kivy garden graph (sin wave) and I'm having difficulty implementing this within my app.

Here is the code that I'm working with

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy


from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.switch import Switch
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot
from math import sin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from kivy.graphics import *

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '480')

Builder.load_string("""

<Menuscreen>:
    #Handling the gesture event.
    ScreenManager:
        id: manager
        Screen:
            id: main_screen
            name:'main_screen'
            FloatLayout:

                MyGraph:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: 800,600
                    pos: 25,25



""")

class MyGraph(Graph):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGraph, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.xlabel = 'This is the X axis'
        self.ylabel = 'This is the Y axis'
        self.x_ticks_minor = 5
        self.x_ticks_major = 25
        self.y_ticks_major = 1
        self.y_grid_label = True
        self.x_grid_label = True
        self.x_grid = True
        self.y_grid = True
        self.xmax = 100
        self.xmin = -0
        self.ymin = -1
        self.ymax = 1
        self.plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
        self.plot.points = [(x, sin(x / 10.)) for x in range(0, 100)]
        self.add_plot(self.plot)

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
menu_screen = MenuScreen(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu_screen)


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

All of the axis labels seem to appear but the points on the graph do not appear. Is there something that I am missing to get this to appear? Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Mostafar at Github asked this same question, and thanks to @Tshirtman, the following answer was provided:

mostafar commented on Apr 27, 2014 After a chat with @tshirtman, He found out the problem is with stencilbuffer and by changing line 139 of init.py of graph module to:

self._fbo = Fbo(size=self.size, with_stencilbuffer=False)

It will be visible in my example, but then there will be many problems with new features of graph (SmoothLinePlot).

Link: https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph/issues/7